# show the image based on a condition

Tags: angular, typescript

I want the image tag to show the image depending on a condition.

I tried the below code but it is not showing me the image

```
<img src="{{row.image}}!=null?'data:image/jpeg;base64,{{row.image}}':'./assets/img/quill1.png'">
```

Can someone tell what is that i am doing wrong.

Comment: this logic should be wraped inside ts file not HTML! src tag is responsible to display the image either it should base64 or physical paht

Comment: I saw few examples where it is in html file

Comment: yes and it will work! but it will not easy to maintain and keep the code clean!

Answer (score 1):

Use *ngIf to conditionally show elements

```
<img *ngIf="row.image" [attr.src]="'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + row.image" />
<img *ngIf="!row.image" src="./assets/img/quill1.png" />
```

Edit:

And you would ideally build the full base64 src string in your ts

Edit 2:

Example of conditional logic in attributes: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfbsid

**This is not my recommended approach, just an example**

Comment: i have seen few examples where we can do in this way so wanted to check if that is possible

Comment: It is possible to use conditional logic, but I wouldn't say it's better. Example of conditional image url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfbsid

Comment: What you are saying is `ternary` operator and using that on `html`.

Comment: @Mridul not particularly nice, but is possible

Comment: @KurtHamilton, i know both the ways just saying what he's trying to refer.

Answer (score 0):

So you can split this into two elements:

```
<img *ngIf="row.image" [src]="'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + row.image" />
<img *ngIf="!row.image" src="./assets/img/quill1.png" />
```

or you can bind the result to a get function in your `.ts` file:

html:

```
<img [src]="getImage"/>
```

ts:

```
get getImage() {
       return  this.row.image!=null?'data:image/jpeg;base64'+this.row.image:'./assets/img/quill1.png'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Sometimes browser does not support the untrusted URL that is the reason you should use **bypassSecurityTrustUrl** due to security issues. You can see the documentation https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

**component.ts**

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'; 

constructor(private xss: DomSanitizer) {}

safeURL(url: string): any {
    return this.xss.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
}
```

**component.html**

```
<img [src]="row.image?safeURL('data:image/jpeg;base64,'+row.image):'/assets/img/quill1.png'"  alt="Avatar">
```

Or

```
<img [src]="safeURL('data:image/jpeg;base64,'+row.image)" onError="this.src='/assets/img/quill1.png'" alt="Avatar">
```

Or

```
<img *ngIf="row.image; else noAvatar;" [src]="safeURL('data:image/jpeg;base64,'+row.image)" alt="Avatar"/> 
<ng-template #noAvatar>
  <img [src]="'./assets/img/quill1.png'" alt="No Avatar">
</ng-template>
```